# Select the specific column from csv and update the another csv

Tags: python, shell, csv, parsing, scripting

I have a directory which contains many folder with the .csv files and i need to select a particular column from all the .csv and append in another result.csv

Comment: Look up `csvkit`.

Answer (score 0):

You should read all csv files one by one with os library and read/keep the specific column that you want, like this

```
csv_file = pd.read_csv("csv_name_from_os.csv") 
column_val_list = csv_file.specific_column_name._ndarray_values
```

then you can concat multiple columns with

```
result = pd.concat([result, dat2], axis=1)
```

at the end you should save the frame as csv file.